# Drop the sql file to network share mentioned in bcp command

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, bcp

I  have a  sql query where it compiles good with data and i was able to drop the file to MRS-dr01 server where all the tables and stored procedures are stored on the same server, but I'm trying to change the path  to drop the files on different shared network path.

I already tried changing path but it didn't work

Comment: Does the SQL Server service account have access to said new share? What does "didn't work" mean (what was the error)?

Comment: @Larnu SQLState = 08001, NativeError = 1326
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [1326].

Comment: @Larnu can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem...

".... -t "|" -S str-fshare...."

The -S option is used to specify the SQL Server to connect to to pull data FROM (in your case because you are using "queryout"). The -S option should still be the sse-dr01 server... that is still where the data is, correct? You just want to change where the sse-dr01 data is being sent out to file?

If you want to change where the data is going OUT to, just change the path as you already have, but leave the -S option alone.

```
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select * from testfdb.dbo.Batch_1" queryout "\\str-fshare\Departments\IT\Documentation\Daily Operations\Experian\EX_BCH.csv" -T -c -t  "|" -S sse-dr01'
```

My guess is there is NO sql server running on str-fshare and that is why you are getting the error you did. BCP is looking for a SQL Server called "str-fshare"

Comment: that is a different error than you were getting before. You are looking at a new problem now and your first problem is addressed. Your original post is answered, correct? You just had the wrong server name, that is why you were given the error "could not open connection to SQL Server". You should open another question for the other error. Moderators wont like continued troubleshooting tucked into comments.

Comment: got it. If this answer above did address your first problem, please do mark the answer as accepted.